# Google Authorization Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch with Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, google-api, jupyter-notebook, google-oauth, jupyter-lab

There are [many posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680886/redirect-uri-mismatch-the-redirect-uri-in-the-request-does-not-match-the-ones-au) dealing with `redirect_uri` issues for accessing Google APIs, but I have not been able to find one that directly addresses my particular situation.

Specifically, I am trying to access the Google Search Console API from Jupyter Lab. When testing in iPython via iTerm, [this example](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/docs/quickstart/quickstart.py#L33-L50) from the Google Docs team worked like a charm. Now that I've switch the code to a notebook though, I'm running into this issue:

> Authorization Error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI
>   in the request, http://localhost:65490/, does not match the ones
>   authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect
>   URIs [...]

I've followed the instructions from other posts to add a generic `localhost` to my authorized redirect URIs like so:

```
{
    "web":{
        "client_id":"[...]",
        "project_id":"[...]",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret":"[...]",
        "redirect_uris":[
            "http://localhost"
        ]
    }
}
```

In my code I've even included this in the `kwargs` of the `from_client_secrets_file` method which *I think* [this documentation](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html#google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file) says is ok:

```
def prepare_credentials():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists(SECRETS_PATH + 'token.pickle'):
        with open(SECRETS_PATH + 'token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS, SCOPES,redirect_uri='http://localhost')
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open(SECRETS_PATH + 'token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds
```

The interesting thing I've noticed is that while I am interacting with Jupyter Lab at `http://localhost:8889/lab`, the `redirect_uri` this code randomly changes the port in the `redirect_uri`. So for example if I run the code once, it will try `http://localhost:65490/`, but if I run it again I might get `http://localhost:51648/` (and so on...). Also, I don't know if this matters, but I'm running Jupyter Lab in Chrome, whereas my default browser (and where I am logged in to the Google profile I use for this work) is Firefox. The flow opens Firefox, but I am stuck at this 400 error...

Comment: Did you find a solution? Mine is also changing the port everytime I run the code.

Comment: @LucSpan i did! when configuring oauth, make sure to specify a uri, such as localhost:8080. _then_ use that in the `run_local_server` method, such as `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)`. i have a long blog post with an example here http://blog.measureallthethin.gs/apis/seo/pandas/jupyter/2020/05/17/google-search-console-via-python.html