# Azure Ad authentication reply url contains http instead of https with .netcore middleware - how to enforce https?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-middleware

Notice the http instead of https. When I replace http with https the I am redirected and successfully receive the bearer token. How do I enforce the url generated by the middleware to contain https?

Middleware:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Request created upon redirection:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/6957e{...}825/oauth2/authorize?
    client_id=747{...}9810&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F {... continued url ...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the comment added by Stef Heyenrath on the Stackoverflow post: [How to set redirect_uri protocol to HTTPS in Azure Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189883/how-to-set-redirect-uri-protocol-to-https-in-azure-web-apps)

Step 1 : configure the ForwardedHeadersOptions

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.RequireHeaderSymmetry = false;
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;

    // TODO : it's a bit unsafe to allow all Networks and Proxies...
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```

Step 2 : UseForwardedHeaders in the public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,

```
IHostingEnvironment env) method

app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Step 3 : Only use UseHttpsRedirection for production

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    // Forward http to https (only needed for local development because the Azure Linux App Service already enforces https)
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For people using docker and deploy to Azure App Services:
add the following in your DockerFile:
ENV ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true

It turned out that AAD redirect uri was set to http instead of https

Comment: Same problem in Docker and I fixed adding the ENV variable in the Dockerfile as suggested. Thank you @jawa

Answer (score 1):

Based on  the Microsoft documentation you should use `UseHttpsRedirection` to achieve this:

> - The HTTPS Redirection Middleware (UseHttpsRedirection) to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

[ASP.NET Core Enforce HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

The `.UseHttpsRedirection()` will issue HTTP response codes redirecting from http to https.

Comment: Just validated that I have this line in my Startup file. app.UseHttpsRedirection(); I also recreated the app service and created a new Azure Ad application and it persists on building the return url as HTTP.

Comment: A port must be available for the middleware to redirect an insecure request to HTTPS. If no port is available: Redirection to HTTPS doesn't occur. The middleware logs the warning "Failed to determine the https port for redirect." Set HttpsRedirectionOptions.HttpsPort. In host configuration.

Comment: Additional information: I am running from a docker container with exposed ports 80/8081. The app service appears to bind on 8081.

Comment: Your comment about the error displayed was VERY helpful:   2020-09-29T13:21:55.912618983Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
2020-09-29T13:21:55.912644984Z       Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

Comment: A "HTTPS port"*, only accepts HTTPS (,so no HTTP) connections.Also  default ports is 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.Plese try adding   `services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => options.HttpsPort = 443);` in your startup.cs page.Please also call `app.UseHsts()` after  `app.UserHttpsRedirection()`

Comment: Found the solution to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189883/how-to-set-redirect-uri-protocol-to-https-in-azure-web-apps

Comment: Thank you for all your help Hari Krishna. You set me down the right path!